# Most likely cause of hair loss in dogs

Tags: dogs, health, veterinarian

I have what I think might be a very good controlled experiment since I have two dogs.  They are both Great Pyrenees.  One is "mine" a female 7 years old and has a thick impermeable healthy white coat.

[EDIT: photos provided here now]
[[image: chest area]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnaJa.jpg)
[[image: back area]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfIX0.jpg)

The other is a rescue dog, about the same age.  He has lived with the female for about 3-4 years.  He's steadily lost hair and his flesh is a combination of pink and black skin underneath.  He still has full hair around his face and chest/shoulders. But it's VERY thin back of that, and almost gone on his belly.  He also has "tags" of flesh on his stomach area.  And, he's skinny, and doesn't smell good even when he's bathed.

He's got access to as much food as he wants (dry) but has stayed skinny.

Obviously, it's not contagious as Wendy hasn't gotten this at all.

I am sorry I haven't put a lot of effort into him but have some money to at least try something.  Is it possible this is worms?  If so what type, and what type of medicine should I try?  Honestly, I don't have the budget for the 150-300 that a vet would charge, but am willing to spend 30-40 on an OTC or internet-order treatment.  Thanks.

Oh, one more thing, he's not extremely active, but no obvious sign of lethargy.  Pretty quiet though.

Answer (score 2):

This honestly needs attention from a veterinarian - skin issues need to be seen in person as diagnostics need to be ran in order to figure out what's wrong. There are numerous reasons for hair loss - from allergies, parasites, thyroid, infection etc.. Sadly there is no medication that anyone online can recommend for you.

Have you tried calling animal shelters/rescues to help you? Some can help low income families get treatment for their pets.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different conditions and parasites that cause dogs to lose fur.
Some can be solved with medicated baths and others with medicine.
Parasites can cause a fur loss called mange but the dog is normally itchy and very red and sore.
They could have allergies.
Probably the best thing to do would to take them to the vet to get a proper diagnosis and some medication.
Hope this helps.